# The whole map rendering every time when state got changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react native maps in my project. I want to draw polygons based on the search without load the whole map again. The whole map is re-render instead of drawing the polygon itself.

I have the logic like these.

_getMapData will render the below map and polygon based on the search. It will call on every filter change or componentWillMount.

```
<MapView  initialRegion={region} zoomEnrabled>
              {mapData.map((data, index) => (
                <MapView.Polygon
                  key={index}
                  coordinates={data.coordinates}
                  fillColor={data.properties.polygonColor}
                  strokeColor="rgba(88, 136, 177, 0)"
                  strokeWidth={0}
                  tappable
                />
              ))}
</MapView>
```

the search filter screen is different and when the search is filled just navigating to the map screen. Map screen has the _getMapData function.

Comment: Where is `mapData` stored at? If it's stored inside component's state then nothing you could do - state update will trigger rendering of component and its children. If you stored it in external provider, like redux or react context then there might be some solutions.

Comment: yes it is stored on the redux

Answer (score 0):

Of course the component will re-render after every change on the state, this is how it works on react/react-native and could be a common issue sometimes.

However, you can use [shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to prevent that the whole component re-render again once the state changes.

Comment: If we prevent that the whole component re-render again can we draw the polygon only if state changes instead of whole map loading again?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [last comment from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701961/the-whole-map-rendering-every-time-when-state-got-changed?noredirect=1#comment98124242_55701961) that the data is stored in redux, there is one possible solution: excluding any data related to polygon from component holding `<Map>` to avoid re-render. Polygons should be rendered inside another component, using [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) provided in React v16+.

```
class MapPolygons extends React.Component {
   ...
   render() {
       return (
          <>
              {mapData.map((data, index) => (
                <MapView.Polygon
                  key={index}
                  coordinates={data.coordinates}
                  fillColor={data.properties.polygonColor}
                  strokeColor="rgba(88, 136, 177, 0)"
                  strokeWidth={0}
                  tappable
                />
              ))}
          </>
       )
   }
}
```

and in your original component:

```
<MapView  initialRegion={region} zoomEnrabled>
  <MapPolygons />
</MapView>
```

Again, `mapData` or any trace of data which can update polygon should be removed from component containing `<MapView>`, or if it's not possible, they should be handle in `shouldComponentUpdate` to avoid unwanted re-render.